# D3 force directed graph with images on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, d3.js, svg, graph

I'm trying to improve my D3 force directed graph's performance. Currently it uses SVG elements but as soon as the number of nodes reaches 500 and links ~ 2000 it becomes almost impossible to use. I'm looking at some alternative ways of rendering the graph.

Canvas seems to be a nice option :
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3180395

**But is it possible to attach images to nodes on canvas as it's done here:**
http://bl.ocks.org/eesur/be2abfb3155a38be4de4

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `drawImage()`. Here's [some documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage)

And yeah, canvas is a good approach or speeding things up — within reason. The force layout itself takes a bunch of CPU cycles no matter how you render it, and your numbers are already quite high for that. Also, while rendering 500 circles into a canvas at 60fps (fps = frames per second) should be doable, rendering 2000 links in addition will already start slowing things down too. Still, it'll be much better than SVG.

In order to know whether — and how much — your optimizations are improving performance, consider using something like [stats.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/stats.js/)

Comment: @andreybavt, in addition to meetamit's advice, I'd recommend adopting d3v4, it's includes better [canvas support](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/95aa92e2f4e8345aaa55a4a94d41ce37).